# How to reverse for loop?

Tags: java, loops

I have a method with some logic

first it looked like:

```
static boolean checkWin(char dot) {
    if (map[0][0] == dot && map[0][1] == dot && map[0][2] == dot) {
        return true;
    }
    //more code
    if (map[0][2] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][0] == dot) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

With loops I refactored the method:

```
static boolean checkWin(char dot) {
    for (int i = 0; i <map.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (map[0][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            if (map[1][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            if (map[2][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            if (map[i][0] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            if (map[i][1] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            if (map[i][2] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }

            if (map[i][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                return true;
            }

            if (map[0][2] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][0] == dot) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a problem with this line of code:

```
if (map[0][2] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][0] == dot) 
    return true;
}
```

I need to get `map[i][?]`, `?` should assume the value 2, 1 and 0 when `i` equals to 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you actually need `i` to have these values or do you just need to print it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to decrease it

```
 for (int i = 2; i > = 0; i--) {
            
 }
```

i will be `2 1 0`

**P.S**
I think you missed `2` there

**P.S**
If I understand your question correctly, you need to have `2 1 0` inside loop without modifying `for` itself? In that case try:

```
 for (int i = 3; i < 3; i++) {
   ... 2 - i
 }
```

Comment: I need to get results from the same loop not another.

Comment: @Dartweiler then please edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: @Dartweiler And by the way, that's not possible without changing the value of `i` and mangling the entire loop. So please also explain *why* you need that.

Comment: maybe OP's looking for `System.out.println(2-i);` (but that won't be `i`'s value, and using `i = 2-i` would break the iteration)

Comment: @Aaron I bet they do, but it's unclear, and answering unclear questions always ends up in "that's not what I meant"